# SocketCAN in dotnet core

Tags: linux, .net-core, can-bus

I am writing software for the device on Linux, and which should work with the CAN interface. Ideally, I would like to work with the interface without connecting third-party libraries from c ++. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem using native function. Here example to bind socket, can read and write message with native functions write( or aio_write) and read. [CanPublisher in UDSim](https://github.com/zombieCraig/UDSim/blob/master/Peach.Core.OS.Linux/Publishers/CanPublisher.cs) as example

```
const int Siocgifindex = 0x8933;
private const int PfCan = 29;
private const int SockRaw = 3;
private const int CanRaw = 1;
private const int CanMtu = 16;

[DllImport("libc", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern int socket(int domain, int type, int protocol);
[DllImport("libc", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern int ioctl(int fd, int request, ref Ifreq mtu);
[DllImport("libc", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern int bind(int fd, ref SockaddrCan addr, int addrlen);


[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct SockaddrCan
{
    public ushort can_family;
    public int can_ifindex;
    public uint rx_id;
    public uint tx_id;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
struct Ifreq
{
    public Ifreq(string ifr_name)
    {
        this.ifr_name = ifr_name;
        this.ifr_ifindex = 0; // ifru_ivalue
        this.ifru_mtu = 0;
    }

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 16)]
    public string ifr_name;
    public int ifr_ifindex;
    public uint ifru_mtu;
}

var addr = new SockaddrCan();
var s = socket(PfCan, SockRaw, CanRaw);
var ifr = new Ifreq("vcan0");
var ret = ioctl(s, Siocgifindex, ref ifr);
addr.can_ifindex = ifr.ifr_ifindex;
addr.can_family = PfCan;
ret = bind(s, ref addr, Marshal.SizeOf(addr));
```

Answer (score 1):

I have written a .NET managed wrapper library for SocketCAN called SocketCAN# (SocketCANSharp): https://github.com/derek-will/SocketCANSharp

SocketCAN# enables utilizing Raw CAN, ISO-TP, Broadcast Manager, and J1939 sockets in a .NET application on Linux.

Some sample code:

```
IEnumerable<CanNetworkInterface> collection = CanNetworkInterface.GetAllInterfaces(true);

var iface = collection.FirstOrDefault(i =>  i.Name.Equals("vcan0"));

using (var rawCanSocket = new RawCanSocket())
{
    rawCanSocket.Bind(iface);
    int bytesWritten = rawCanSocket.Write(
        new CanFrame(0x123, new byte[] { 0x45, 0x67, 0x89, 0xab, 0xcd, 0xef }));
}
```

Underneath the library uses P/Invoke to call the native libc functions and marshal the various types back and fourth between the managed and unmanaged code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the [SocketCAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SocketCAN) library that is part of Linux.
You can also use candump and cansend to help you develop and also look at the [candump.c](https://github.com/linux-can/can-utils/blob/master/candump.c) and [cansend.c](https://github.com/linux-can/can-utils/blob/master/cansend.c) source files for inspiration.

I see there is a dotnet tag, if you want to use CAN in dotnet I suggest you write a small C library to handle the CAN stuff. Then marshal that to dotnet, once you have access in dotnet you can wrap things in classes and create whatever abstractions you need.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I did. I could do without my own libraries on C, only using native functions